# Transparent QQuickView

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I tried to make a transparent QQuickView and use it with my own render engine for user interface, However i figured out that Transparent QQuickViews are not supported (on Windows 7). Is there a good reason why Qt doesn't give support transparency for QWindows on Windows 7?